# C# custom attribute validation in console environment

Tags: c#, validation, attributes

My question is about validation using custom attributes in C#.

I don't quite understand how the validation works. I have declared an attribute with the validation rule in it but when the error should be thrown it is not.

Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class NotNullAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value is string && (string)value != "")
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Inside the attribute I check if the property is of type string and if its value is an empty string because that is what I have to check.

The task is to check if a property is a `string` and if its an empty string then its not valid, otherwise it is.

My `Person` class:

```
class Person
{
    [NotNull]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here I am applying the custom attribute.

Main method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.Name = "";

        Console.WriteLine("Validation done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This is where I instantiate the `Person` class and assign an empty string to the `Name` property. This is where the error should be thrown I guess.

So my question is why isn't the validation applied? Should I have called the `IsValid` method from the attribute it self somehow?

I would take some explanation about this, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute itself is just a "decorator" of the property. If nothing calls it, it will not be automatically executed nor used.

In your case, however, I don't see the point of using an attribute, when you can use property itself:

```
private string _name = "";

public string Name
{
   get
   {
      return _name;
   }
   set
   {
      if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) )
      {
          //throw or fallback
      }
      else
      {
          _name = value;
      }
   }
}
```

Doing basic value validation is exactly the job property setters are great for. In case someone uses an invalid value, you can throw an exception, or set a fallback value for example.

If you would still prefer using attributes, you still need to have some code that performs the validation itself. And still, anyone can assign any valid value to the property, unless validation is performed.

For example [ASP.NET MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1) uses attribute validation during Model Binding - it checks the validation attributes on the bound model class and verifies it before the action method begins executing.

### Example of attribute validation

Here is a simple example of how to make your code work with reflection.

First here is a slightly updated version of the validation attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class NotNullAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Your code actually only allowed a `null` or `""` value, which I guess is opposite of what you wanted. This version is valid only when the string is not `null` and not empty.

Now create a `Validate` method in your `Program` class:

```
private static bool Validate(object model)
{
    foreach (var propertyInfo in model.GetType().GetProperties())
    {                
        foreach (var attribute in propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
        {
            var notNullAttribute = attribute as NotNullAttribute;
            if (notNullAttribute != null)
            {
                if (!notNullAttribute.IsValid(propertyInfo.GetValue(model)))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This basically gathers all properties of the type of the passed in parameter, checks all attributes of the properties for `NotNullAttribute` and then executes the attribute's `IsValid` method against the current value from the `model`.

Finally here is how you can call it from `Main`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.Name = "d";

    if (Validate(p1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Valid");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Validation done");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Now, if you are planning on adding more validation attributes, I would create an interface first:

```
public interface IValidationAttribute
{
    bool IsValid(object value);
}
```

Then derive all your validation attributes from `IValidationAttribute` and in `Validate` method use `IValidationAttribute` in place of `NotNullAttribute`. This way the code becomes more future-proof as you can just program against the interface and add new validation attributes anytime.

Comment: The point is that I need to solve the task the way I described in the description for school assignment, that is why I asked for help using my approach

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of how this could work with attributes

Comment: Glad it helped, happy coding :-) !

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class BankAccount  
   {  
       public enum AccountType  
       {  
           Saving,  
           Current  
       }  
       [Required(ErrorMessage="First Name Required")]  
       [MaxLength(15,ErrorMessage="First Name should not more than 1`5 character")]  
       [MinLength(3,ErrorMessage="First Name should be more than 3 character")]  
       public string AccountHolderFirstName { get; set; }  
       [Required(ErrorMessage="Last Name Required")]  
       [MaxLength(15,ErrorMessage="Last Name should not more than 1`5 character")]  
       [MinLength(3,ErrorMessage="Last Name should be more than 3 character")]  
       public string AccountHolderLastName { get; set; }  
       [Required]  
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only Number allowed in AccountNumber")]  
       public string AccountNumber { get; set; }  

       public AccountType AcType { get; set; }  

       [AccountBalaceCheckAttribute]  
       public double AccountBalance { get; set; }  
   }
```

How to Validate

```
public class GenericValidator   
{  
    public static bool TryValidate(object obj, out ICollection<ValidationResult> results)  
    {  
        var context = new ValidationContext(obj, serviceProvider: null, items: null);  
        results = new List<ValidationResult>();  
        return Validator.TryValidateObject(  
            obj, context, results,  
            validateAllProperties: true  
        );  
    }  
}
```

Example

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
{  
    var bankAccount = new BankAccount();  
    ICollection<ValidationResult> lstvalidationResult;  

    bool valid = GenericValidator.TryValidate(bankAccount, out lstvalidationResult);  
    if (!valid)  
    {  
        foreach (ValidationResult res in lstvalidationResult)  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine(res.MemberNames +":"+ res.ErrorMessage);  
        }  

    }  
    Console.ReadLine();  
}
```

Comment: could you please explain the TryValidate() method in a little more details? I don't understand what the ValidationResult and ValidationContext types are, are they predefined or they come from the framework?